# Break an infinit loop when button is pressed

Tags: python, loops, pyqt5

I am currently starting to use PyQt5 and created my first GUI. Now I would like a program that does the following. When Button 'start' is pressed execute 'function' n-times until Button 'stop' is pressed (imagine a stopwatch) if I press Button 'start' again 'function' gets once again executed and so on.

What I tried so far is the following, that can not work, since we are not able to change a variable from outside the loop (mockup-script)

```
class Ui(QtWidgets.QDialog):
def __init__(self):
    super(Ui, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi('interfaceScan.ui', self)
    self.startScan = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'startScan') 
    self.startScan.clicked.connect(self.startPressed)

    self.pauseScan = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'pauseScan')
    self.pauseScan.clicked.connect(self.pausePressed) 

    self.show()

    def startPressed(self):
            global pauseScan
            pauseScan = False 
            dosomething()

    def pausePressed(self):
            global pauseScan
            pausScan = True

def dosomething(): 
    while pauseScan == False: #not needed, but the measurement should be executed periodically until 'pause' is pressed
        print('Running') #in the reals program the measurement will be executed here 
        time.sleep(4) #between each measurement the program needs to wait a cirtain amount of time ~1h  

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this problem? I am now relatively certain that it does not work when using a while loop, so I am open to suggestions on how to change it up!

The purpose of this script will be to control a measurement setup that should run for let's say 1000 cycles, but I would like to be able to break it in between to change so parameters.

Comment: Your `dosomething` function needs to execute in a different thread, so that the interface itself remains responsive (i.e. able to react when you press "Stop") while `dosomething` executes. This topic is a bit more complex than your average SO answer, so I recommend reading this [introduction to multithreading in PyQt](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/concurrent-execution/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/).

Comment: Is `time.sleep(4)` a delay or emulates a time-consuming task?

Comment: I think that you are mistaken when you say that your system, which controls, works only in the main thread.

Comment: time.sleep(4) is just used to not spam the console, but in the real program there is also a wait section between different scans.

Comment: @123einhundert Bypassing the while and sleep The real "dosomething" when it takes to run? please use `@username`

Comment: @123einhundert I recommend you to place your **real code** since it seems that you are not able to set a good example, since depending on what you are really doing, one or another solution could be proposed.

Comment: @S.Nick I've just started programming in Python, so I am a total noob when it comes to using the right terminology. The problem is that I don't want to interrupt the program  performing my measurement making it less "stable" when restricting it to a thread.

Comment: @eyllanesc since I am doing research I am not sure if it is the best idea to publish the automation for my measurements setup jet. Maybe I can state the modules that are included in the autmation...

Comment: @123einhundert We need a good MRE but according to your example we do not know which part of the code is modifiable and which part is not. For example, can I eliminate the while loop and sleep?

Comment: @123einhundert The libraries do not interest us (at least not me) since it does not give us information about anything, what I want is to correctly understand your code, that is, which part is mandatory and which part is modifiable, if you use the while loop + sleep you use it to execute a task periodically so in that case it is better to use a QTimer. If instead you have tasks that consume more than 10 ms then it is necessary to execute it in another thread ....

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, you can eliminate the while loop. The only requirement I have is that I need to repeat my measurement routine until the pause button is pressed. Also, it would be neat if I have the option to wait a certain amount of time between each measurement. The measurement (task) itself takes multiple minutes. The waiting periode between each measurement cycle is in the range of minutes to one houre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the OP points out in the comments, the while loop with the time.sleep() only aims to perform a periodic task but this generates a problem since the time.sleep() freezes the GUI, instead a QTimer must be used:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic


class Ui(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("interfaceScan.ui", self)
        self.startScan.clicked.connect(self.startPressed)
        self.pauseScan.clicked.connect(self.pausePressed)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=4 * 1000, timeout=dosomething)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def startPressed(self):
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, dosomething)
        self.timer.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def pausePressed(self):
        self.timer.stop()


def dosomething():
    print("Running")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```